# pdf-tools asking to be rebuilt when emacs is started

Tags: pdf-tools

My `init.el` file includes the line `(pdf-tools-install)`

Recently whenever I open emacs I get the message

`"Need to (re)build the epdfinfo program, do it now" (y or n)`
which is rather annoying.
I can't quite work out what to do in order to stop this from happening, and I can swear I remember this was not an issue when I originally set up pdf-tools. Has anyone come across this before, and/or know what to do?

Comment: I've had to before. If I recall correctly, I just pressed `y` and everything was fine. What happens when you press `y`?

Comment: I should have made clear that I have been pressing `y` and thankfully everything compiles nicely. However, I would prefer to avoid having to press `y` and wait ~10 seconds to start using emacs.

Comment: Call `M-x pdf-info-check-epdfinfo`. Probably you can fix the problem yourself with the error message emitted by that command. Otherwise add the error message to your question. Maybe, you should run `M-x pdf-info-check-epdfinfo` before running `pdf-tools-install`. One possible reason for `pdf-tools-install` to fail is a wrong configuration of `pdf-info-epdfinfo-program`. If that is the case just delete any customization of that variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just uncomment `;;(pdf-tools-install)` in your `init.el`. If it once installed then it have not to do it every time.
That worked for me, had the same problem.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Please elaborate on your answer. How did that commented line get in the init file in the first place?

Comment: Thanks - I had thought I needed this all the time, since I couldn't install pdf-tools without putting it in the `init.el`, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

For me, when I looked closely at the messages for the compilation, I noticed that it mentioned that automake 1.16.3 couldn't be installed because an earlier version 1.16.3 was already installed. Even so, it told me that it compiled successfully, which I why I previously never looked at the compilation output very closely.

It told me to run `brew upgrade automake`, and after doing so, and recompiling one last time, I no longer get this message. I still have `(pdf-tools-install)` in my .emacs file.